# Save Preset Selections of Visible Layers, to be accessed later via control panel

Tags: adobe-illustrator, template-design

So this is basically me searching for a specialized feature I just hope Illustrator has, or finding a helpful alternative.

The project I'm working on requires multiple combinations of many different symbols, to later be printed. I'm trying to find a way to save combinations for later so that they can be easily accessed without effectively duplicating everything (hopefully-)unnecessarily by saving a different Ai file for each.

Can anybody think of anything??? Thank you all so much.

Comment: what do you mean symbols? are these symbols converted to AI symbols?

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid duplicates by placing links of the individual artworks (I'm assuming you are refering to symbols in the real world way, as in a little piece of art, and not in the technical illustrator symbol object way) of the symbols in the 'set' files you are saving.

That way you can use a single base file for each symbol. This way you can make corrections to the base file, and these corrections will automatically (You may need to open and save the 'set' file) happen in each set where it is used.

Comment: This sounds like an important work-around if I were to just create duplicate files. Thanks.